# Remove a column with bad quality data if there is good quality data for the same period

Tags: r, if-statement, data-manipulation

I have the following problem: My data contains good and bad quality data. So e.g. For the time 2017-12-31, I have a column with good quality data `(Quality = a)` with the value 800 and bad quality data `(Quality = b)` with the value 750.

```
  Quality       Time Value
1       a 2017-12-31   800
2       a 2018-12-31   500
3       b 2017-12-31   750
4       b 2018-12-31   480
5       b 2019-12-31   200
```

Sample data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(Quality = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b"), Time = c("2017-12-31", "2018-12-31", "2017-12-31", "2018-12-31", "2019-12-31"), Value = c(800, 500, 750, 480, 200))
```

I want to keep the "bad quality" data `(Quality = b)` only when there is no "good quality" data `(Quality = a)` for each period `(Time)`.

Hence, the expected output is:

```
  Quality       Time Value
1       a 2017-12-31   800
2       a 2018-12-31   500
3       b 2019-12-31   200
```

I tried to solve this problem with an if statement, but failed. My real data has over 10000 rows and multiple dates. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the help of `match` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Time) %>%
  slice(first(na.omit(match(c('a', 'b'), Quality)))) %>%
  ungroup

#  Quality Time       Value
#  <chr>   <chr>      <dbl>
#1 a       2017-12-31   800
#2 a       2018-12-31   500
#3 b       2019-12-31   200
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by sorting by quality and then deduplicating by time.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
arrange(Quality) %>% #sort by quality so a is first
distinct(Time, .keep_all = TRUE) #keep only the first row for each time value and keep all columns
```

If you'd prefer base R you can do the same thing using `order(Quality)` and `df[which(!duplicated(df$Time)),]`.

Comment: Thanks for the awnser. But since my real data is more complicated this sadly does not work. But thanks!

Comment: No problem. Would you mind explaining why it doesn't work for your data? Could be helpful for me.

Comment: I actualy have more than two quality standards, like "c" but there is no other data for that time period, only c quality. Furthermore, the Quality is not reportet as "a", "b" etc. but as another string. Also I have different individuals for each value etc. which complicates everything even more. So the time must not be unique, but in your solution there are only unique times. But thanks for your help, thats why I upvoted your question :)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense--more than two values is fine but the other parts could cause problems without a group_by and perhaps non-lexicographical sorting. Thanks for letting me know!